# Yast default password

Tags: passwords, opensuse, yast

I was configuring accounts of users in Open Suse 11.3 from Yast. I knew the password of each one, but the problem is that when I went into Yast *User and Group Management* there was six asterisks in the password input. I ignore that, i though it was the password I set before.

But when I went into lockscreen, I typed the password and it does not work, so I guess that the password have been change to that Yast default.

The question is, what is that password?

Comment: There is no default password, and since unix systems never store the original password, those asterisks were probably dummy characters to show that there was a password present but the system had literally no idea what is was or how many there were. I suspect you inadvertently changed the password and didn't realize you had. You will probably need to use a recovery root shell and `passwd -u eversor` from the command line to reset it to a new value. I do not have any experience with Suse directly but this is true of every unix since about 1970.

Comment: Are you now locked out of your system - is that what you need help with?

Comment: @msw i fixed it  the problem was I accidentally disable login for those users instead of disabling auto login

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" to your title. Add an answer that explains what the solution was, or if it's not a real problem just delete the question.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question (in the answer box, below) and mark it as accepted if you are happy wit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I disabled login instead of disabling auto login.